# Function not accessing memory correctly in C

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

Basically the title. I have a function which is receiving two pointers to two items of a BST to verify a few conditions (I won't go into details very much since my problem doesn't lie there). The very weird thing is that, after calling the search function for BSTs to get pointers to the two items I want to examine, they seem to work perfectly, since a printf of their key field works fine. After calling my function and passing the two pointers as parameters, somehow, every access to their fields results in a segmentation fault.
Here's my code with the searches and the call to my bugged function (it's part of a bigger function, a few variables were declared above, nothing too integral though):

```
napoli = scanf("%d", &distanza);
        int distanza2 = -1;
        napoli = scanf("%d", &distanza2);
        if(distanza == distanza2){
            printf("%d\n", distanza);
            return;
        }
        int flag = 1;
        stazione *station1 = search(distanza, station->root, &flag);
        stazione *station2 = search(distanza2, station->root, &flag);
        printf("Stazioni %d e %d in arrivo\n", station1->distanza, station2->distanza);
        pianificaPercorso(station1, station2);
        return;
```

and here's the function pianificaPercorso:

```
void pianificaPercorso(stazione *station1, stazione *station2){
    printf("Pianificando stazioni %d e %d", station1->distanza, station2->distanza); 
    pila *p = NULL;
    stazione *progress = station2; //marks which stations have to be added to the route
    stazione *checking = NULL; //checks which stations are reachable
    int flag = 0; //once we've checked station 1, this becomes 1 and we can add a stop
    int gtfo = 1;
    if(station2->distanza < station1->distanza){
        checking = successore(station2);
        while(progress != station1){ //continue until we reach station 1
            while(flag == 0 && checking != NULL){
                if(checking == station1){
                    flag = 1;
                }
                if(reachable(checking, progress)){
                    progress = checking;
                    gtfo = 1;
                }
                checking = successore(checking);
            }
            if(gtfo == 0){ //if progress wasn't modified, we must exit
                printf("nessun percorso\n");
                return;
            }
            push(p, progress->distanza);
            checking = successore(progress);
            flag = 0;
            gtfo = 0;
        } //after this, the whole route will be pushed into the stack

    } else {
        checking = predecessore(station2);
        while(progress != station1){ //continue until we reach station 1
            while(flag == 0){
                if(checking == station1){
                    flag = 1;
                }
                if(reachable(checking, progress)){
                    progress = checking;
                    gtfo = 1;
                }
                checking = predecessore(checking);
            }
            if(gtfo == 0){ //if progress wasn't modified, we must exit
                printf("nessun percorso\n");
                return;
            }
            push(p, progress->distanza);
            checking = predecessore(progress);
            flag = 0;
            gtfo = 0;
        }
    }
    while(empty(p)){
        printf("%d ", pop(p));
    }
    printf("%d\n", station2->distanza);
    return;
}
```

For reference, here are also my structs and my search function:

```
typedef struct car{
    int autonomia;
    struct car *left;
    struct car *right;
    struct car *p;
}car;

typedef struct carTree{
    int nodi;
    car *root;
}carTree;

typedef struct stazione{
    int distanza;
    carTree cars;
    struct stazione *left;
    struct stazione *right;
    struct stazione *p;

}stazione;

typedef struct tree{
    int nodi;
    stazione *root;
}tree;



typedef struct pila{
    int value;
    struct pila *top;
    struct pila *next;
}pila;


stazione *search(int x, stazione *t, int *flag){
    if(t == NULL){
        *flag = 0;
        return NULL;
    }
    if(t->distanza == x){
        return t; //sta prendendo null per qualche motivo
    }
    else if(t->distanza < x){
        return search(x, t->right, flag);
    }
    else {
        return search(x, t->left, flag);
    }    
}
```

I tried performing the searches inside pianifica-percorso, by passing the keys and the pointer to the BST itself instead of the two pointers, but it still wouldn't work

Comment: Suggestion: install a recent [Debian](https://debian.org/) distribution on your computer, with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler and [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger. Spend several days reading documentation. Then compile your code using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Improve your code to get no warnings.

Comment: .... use a version control system, e.g. [git](https://git-scm.com/). Use the GDB debugger. Learn about [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Read much more about [C language and library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c)

Comment: I suspect this is *not* the case since the variable names appear Latin-based, but GTFO has a more modern meaning of "get the f**k out" :-)

Comment: If you don't want to debug, read the documentation about `assert()` and add LOTS to this code... This code looks like it's a prime candidate for "following the NULL pointer"...

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu, and I have ran GDB, ASAN and Valgrind, all 3 could only tell that there was a segfault inside pianifica-percorso and that was it. I've also been compiling with the `-Wall Werror` flags, and there were no warnings. Just did a rundown with `-g` active, but no extra info were given.
And yes, gtfo means exactly that. I ran out of names

Comment: @AndreaColombo then start using it. We are not a free debugging service

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: I don't know exactly what the problem is without seeing the whole code, but I can suggest learning about assertions. Just place as many asserts as you can in your code, testing even the things that you think are obvious. For example, is your `search` function, instead of commenting that "it's getting null for some reason", assert on the arguments and figure out where that null comes from.